# Add input node for hash table

Tags: tables, nodes

[Beginner]

I want to draw a hash table with a hash function node that takes multiple documents and write into the hash table. the Current Latex code creates the hash table but I'm not sure how to add a node the points to the table and have multiple inputs.
Below is the current output and code (image shows the desired output)

Thank you in advance!

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (0);
    \foreach \t/\n[count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as\j using int(\i+1)] in {
        $d_{3} \rightarrow d_{16}$/ 000 ,
        $d_{5} \rightarrow d_{23} \rightarrow d_{74} \rightarrow d_{101} \rightarrow d_{105}$/001  ,
        /010  ,
        $d_{1} \rightarrow d_{7}$/ 011,
        /100  ,
        $d_{93}$/101 ,
        $d_{46} \rightarrow d_{63} \rightarrow d_{89}$/110 ,
        $d_{10} \rightarrow d_{28} \rightarrow d_{35} \rightarrow d_{110}$/111
    }
    \node at(\i.south)[anchor=north,draw,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2.5em,outer sep=0pt](\j){\n}
    node at(\j.west)[align=right,left]{\i} 
    node at(\j.east)[align=left,right,xshift=-.7em]{$\rightarrow$ \t};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

**Desired output:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion below uses the `calc` library to calculate some coordinates. Moreover, I use the `arrows` library for the `stealth'` arrow tip. I add the options `[>=stealth',shorten <=1mm,shorten >=1mm]` to the `tikzpicture` environment to change the arrow tips and to make sure that lines start and stop at a distance of `1mm` from the nodes and coordinates. The code for the added part:

```
    \coordinate (cntr) at ($0.5*(4.west)+0.5*(5.west)$);
    \node[draw](f)at($(cntr)+(-2,0)$){$f()$};
    \draw[->] (f) -- (cntr);
    
    \foreach \i/\y/\in in {1/1.5/150,2/1/160,3/0.5/170,4/0/180,n/-1.5/-150} {
      \node (d\i) at ($(f)+(-3,\y)$) {$d_\i$};
      \draw[->] (d\i) to[out=0,in=\in] (f);
    }
    \draw[dotted,thick] (d4) -- (dn);
    \draw[dotted,thick] (f) ++(-1.7,-0.1) -- +(0,-0.95);
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth',shorten <=1mm,shorten >=1mm]
    \coordinate (0);
    \foreach \t/\n[count=\i from 0,evaluate=\i as\j using int(\i+1)] in {
        $d_{3} \rightarrow d_{16}$/ 000 ,
        $d_{5} \rightarrow d_{23} \rightarrow d_{74} \rightarrow d_{101} \rightarrow d_{105}$/001  ,
        /010  ,
        $d_{1} \rightarrow d_{7}$/ 011,
        /100  ,
        $d_{93}$/101 ,
        $d_{46} \rightarrow d_{63} \rightarrow d_{89}$/110 ,
        $d_{10} \rightarrow d_{28} \rightarrow d_{35} \rightarrow d_{110}$/111
    }
    \node at(\i.south)[anchor=north,draw,minimum height=2em,minimum width=2.5em,outer sep=0pt](\j){\n}
    node at(\j.west)[align=right,left]{\i} 
    node at(\j.east)[align=left,right,xshift=-.7em]{$\rightarrow$ \t};

    \coordinate (cntr) at ($0.5*(4.west)+0.5*(5.west)$);
    \node[draw](f)at($(cntr)+(-2,0)$){$f()$};
    \draw[->] (f) -- (cntr);
    
    \foreach \i/\y/\in in {1/1.5/150,2/1/160,3/0.5/170,4/0/180,n/-1.5/-150} {
      \node (d\i) at ($(f)+(-3,\y)$) {$d_\i$};
      \draw[->] (d\i) to[out=0,in=\in] (f);
    }
    \draw[dotted,thick] (d4) -- (dn);
    \draw[dotted,thick] (f) ++(-1.7,-0.1) -- +(0,-0.95);
  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It works.Thank you so much I really appreciate your help and thorough explanation!